# Calling a constructor in a int method C++

Tags: c++, methods, constructor

Alright, I have a constructor called Fractions that takes as parameters two integers, then I'm supposed to have a method called add() which is supposed to be a const int that takes as parameters the constructor Fractions, and then later returns Fractions.

However, I keep receiving the error message: "No suitable conversion function from "Fraction" to "const int" exists"

Been scouring google for the past few hours, but I can't seem to find anything relevant on how to bypass this. Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include "homework3.h"

using namespace std;



//Provide all missing parts for the class declarations
class Fraction {
public:
    Fraction(){

    }
    Fraction(const int numerator, const int denominator) {
        Fraction::numerator = numerator;
        Fraction::denominator = denominator;
    }
    const int add(Fraction &f1) {

        return  f1;

    }
    string getString();

private:
    int numerator = 0;
    int denominator = 0;

};

string Fraction::getString() {
    //Returns a string of the fraction. 
    stringstream ss;
    ss << numerator << "/" << denominator;
    return ss.str();
}


int main() {

    //Test book problems
    Fraction f1(3, 5);
    Fraction f2(7, 8);

    Fraction f3 = f1.add(f2);
    Fraction f4 = f1.add(4);
    Fraction f5 = f1 + f2;
    cout << f3.getString() << endl;  //These should display 59/40
    cout << f4.getString() << endl;  //These should display 23/5
    cout << f5.getString() << endl;  //These should display 59/40

    f3 = f1.subtract(f2);
    f4 = f1.subtract(4);
    f5 = f1 - f2;
    cout << f3.getString() << endl;  //These should display -11/40
    cout << f4.getString() << endl;  //These should display -17/5
    cout << f5.getString() << endl;  //These should display -11/40


    f3 = f1.multiply(f2);
    f4 = f1.multiply(4);
    f5 = f1 * f2;
    cout << f3.getString() << endl;  //These should display 21/40
    cout << f4.getString() << endl;  //These should display 12/5
    cout << f5.getString() << endl;  //These should display 21/40

    f3 = f1.divide(f2);
    f4 = f1.divide(4);
    f5 = f1 / f2;
    cout << f3.getString() << endl;  //These should display 24/35
    cout << f4.getString() << endl;  //These should display 3/20
    cout << f5.getString() << endl;  //These should display 24/35

                                     //Now for some fun...
    f5 = (f1 * f2) / (f3 - f4) + (f5 + f2);
    cout << f5.getString() << endl;  //These should display 10671000/4200000

    cout << "Press any key to continue" << endl;
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There seem to be some confusion. Your function add() takes Fraction and returns int - yet you are trying to return Fraction object from it. Not sure what you really wanna do it.

Comment: Isn't the return value f1 a Fraction?

Comment: Not with the signature that you gave. `const int` is the return value. Which does not make sense. Also your add implementation is not adding anything.

Comment: You you should have 2 functions `Fraction& add(int val)` and `Fraction& add(const Fraction & val)` not `const int add(Fraction &f1)`

Comment: Oh okay I see. For some reason it never occurred to me that I could just declare the method as a Fraction type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call

```
Fraction f4 = f1.add(4);
```

But you don't have any `add` method that takes `const int` as an argument and returns `Fraction`. You should simply implement such method.

Also the `add` method that you've posted returns `Fraction` and not an int as you specified in the header. If you want it to return an `int` you can simply divide numerator by denominator. However, note that if you have e.g. 1/2, the result will be 0. If this is not what you intend, consider using `float` or `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: I took out a lot of coding too make the post less clunky, but I do have one.  It still gives me the same error message, though.

Comment: const int add(Fraction &f1) 
    {
        return  f1;
    }

Comment: And why do you think it returns an `int` if `f1` is `Fraction&`?

Comment: Okay, so how would I change fraction to an int value?

Comment: Maybe divide numerator by denominator?

Comment: Alright, I think the above posters cleared this up for me. Needed two add methods one that takes in ints and the other Fractions. And you were right  the methods shouldn't of been declared ints

Answer (score 0):

This method is causing an error  :

```
const int add(Fraction &f1) 
{
    return  f1;
}
```

The parameter type is Fraction passed by reference and you're returning a const int.

Answer (score 0):

Аdd method should return the int number. Try override cast operator.